# Entry point was not found when. dotnet core 2.0 EfCore

Tags: asp.net-core, autofac, ef-core-2.0

While trying to ensure that my database has been created, I do the following in my statup class:

```
 using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
 {
     var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyContext>();
     context.Database.EnsureCreated();
 }
```

I've registered the context within the ServiceCollection this way:

```
 services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

When calling `EnsureCreated()` I get the following exception:

```
DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[mynamespace.Data.MyDbContext])' on type 'MyDbContext'. ---> Entry point was not found. (See inner exception for details.)

DependencyResolutionException: An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = ChtrDbContext (ReflectionActivator), Services = [chtr.server.data.Data.ChtrDbContext], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[mynamespace.MyDbContext])' on type 'MyDbContext'. ---> Entry point was not found. (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.)
```

It's worth noticing that I use Autofac as my IoC Framework

Comment: Could you share the constructor of `ChtrDbContext` ? do you have any other inner exception ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand Constructor takes in the DbContextOptions<ChtrDbContext> and passes this to its parent, DbContext.

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue, by ensuring that all of my nuget packages were compatible with the dotnet core version.